# Format numbers with jquery numberformatter and format them back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I format numbers of an input field with jquery numberformatter, that works, but I have to format them back in order to do some calculations on the numbers, but that doesn't work. How can I convert the formatted numbers back so that I can use the calculate function?

Here is the JS for the number formatting:

```
 $("[id$='abzug']").keyup(function(){
    $(this).parseNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"ch"});
    $(this).formatNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"ch"});
    val();
 });
```

Here the HTML:

```
  <input class="form-control" id="kunst_abzug" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" id="theater_abzug" type="text">
```

And here the function to calculate the total:

```
function id(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function val(){
val_totalEingespart = parseInt(id("totalEingespart").value) || 0;
val1 = parseInt(id("kunst_abzug").value) || 0;
val2 = parseInt(id("theater_abzug").value) || 0;
var total_abgezogen = val_totalEingespart - val1 - val2;
var total_abgezogenCHF = total_abgezogen.toLocaleString('de-CH');  
id("totalSum2").innerHTML = total_abgezogenCHF + ' CHF';
}
```

I also created a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lffpg4xp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `onkeyup="val()` from each input element and add it to the keyup of function in document.ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("[id$='abzug']").keyup(function(){
        $(this).parseNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"ch"});
        $(this).formatNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"ch"});
    val();
     });
 });

function getElementValue(id){
     var num = $('#' + id).val();
     return $.parseNumber(num, {format:"####", locale:"ch"});
}

function val(){
    val_totalEingespart = parseInt(getElementValue("totalEingespart")) ? parseInt(getElementValue("totalEingespart")) :  0;
    val1 = parseInt(getElementValue("kunst_abzug")) ? parseInt(getElementValue("kunst_abzug")) : 0;
    val2 = parseInt(getElementValue("theater_abzug")) ?  parseInt(getElementValue("theater_abzug")) : 0;
    var total_abgezogen = val_totalEingespart - val1 - val2;
    $("#totalSum2")[0].innerHTML = total_abgezogen.toLocaleString('de-CH') + ' CHF';
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lffpg4xp/4/)

Comment: i updated the post, but your answer does not solve my problem

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I am subtracting the values of second and third textbox with the value in first textbox. I guessed this from your code.

Comment: it subtracts until you have 4 digits, if you have four it doesn't work anymore

Comment: How can I use the numberformatter function on a div? In order to replace this code: $("#totalSum2")[0].innerHTML = total_abgezogen.toLocaleString('de-CH') + ' CHF'; Because this code is not working reliably on all browsers.

Comment: Which browser are you using? `innerHTML` is supported by all common browsers.

Comment: I was talking about the toLocaleString, but I found a way, maybe not very elegant...

Comment: You can use `$("#totalSum2")[0].innerHTML = $.parseNumber(total_abgezogen, {format:"#,###", locale:"ch"});`